# linux bash and grep bug?

Tags: linux, bash, grep

Doing the following:

First console

```
touch /tmp/test
```

Second console

```
tail -f /tmp/test |grep propo |grep -v miles
```

Third console

```
echo propo >> /tmp/test
```

Second console must show "propo" but it doesn't shows anything, if you run in second console instead:

```
tail -f /tmp/test |grep propo
```

And do `echo propo >> /tmp/test` it will show propo, but the `grep -v` is for miles not for propo

Why?

Test into your own environment if you want, it's pretty obvious but not working.

Comment: it is not working **the way you expected**

Answer (score 1):

> Why?

Most probably because the output of a command when piped to another command is fully buffered, not line buffered. The output could be buffered in the first pipe or by grep.

Use `stdbuf -oL` to force line buffering and `grep --line-buffered` for line buffered grep.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that grep does not use line buffering by default; so the output will be  buffered. You could use `grep --line-buffered`:

```
tail -f /tmp/test | grep --line-buffered propo | grep -v miles
```